# Return count of members with the same parent member in MDX

Tags: count, mdx

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I need to return a count of instances of a member that share the same parent member, and show it on each row, constrained to the member. I'm not sure how best to explain this so instead I've added an image below of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Example data]

So as there are four different members under Delta, the count for Delta is four.

**Why I'm trying to achieve it**

I need to filter the resulting data down to only the last row for each parent, so Delta would only return the row for Member 4. If you can suggest a better way to do this I'd appreciate it.

**What I've tried**

I've been trying to build this as a calculated member, but can't find anything that works. I've gone through all the different COUNT formats on MSDN and can't find one that works.

**CODE**

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Count]
AS COUNT([Person].[Person ID].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT.CHILDREN)

SELECT {
    [Measures].[Value]
    ,[Measures].[Count]
    } ON 0
,NONEMPTY (
            [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS *
            [Transaction Number].[Transaction Number].[Transaction Number].MEMBERS *
            [Person].[Person ID].[Person ID].MEMBERS
            ,[Measures].[Value]
            ) ON 1
FROM (SELECT [Date].[Date].[Date].&[20150107] ON 0 FROM [My DW]);
```

Comment: What is the structure of this dimension `[Person]` - does it have several levels? You are using the function `PARENT`, what is the parent level of `[Person ID]` i.e. the level above `[Person ID]`?

Comment: In the screenprint you have two hierarchies ON ROWS called `Parent` and `Member`- how does this relate to the script you have posted? Is Parent equal to `[Transaction Number]` ?

Comment: Hi @whytheq. I need Parent to be Person ID. I need the count of transactions for each person.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with member [Measures].CountOfSiblings as
COUNT(dim.hier.CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT.CHILDREN)

select dim.hier.level2.members on 1,
{[Measures].[value], [Measures].CountOfSiblings} on 0
from [aw cube]
```

The `.hier.currentmember.parent.children` part will yield a set of all the children for the parent of the *current* member on axis.

It will return the members, the measure value and also the number of children that member's parent has.

**EDIT**
Based on our later conversation, I think the below will more suit the requirements:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Count]
AS COUNT
       (
        NonEmpty
               (
                [Person].[Person ID].MEMBERS, 
                {([Measures].[Value] , [Transaction Number].[Transaction Number].CURRENTMEMBER)}
               )
       )
```

Comment: Can you please share the actual query that you are using?

Comment: Your requirement and the code seems completely incoherent. Can you please again(in the context of the code you added) explain your requirement?

Comment: If my code doesn't match my requirement then it'l be my code that's entirely wrong. I'm trying to get the count of instances of each person, showing against each instance of that person, as shown the image.

Comment: Explain again, What are your "Parent" and "Member" attributes? I don't see any user defined hierarchy in the `[Person]` dimension, looking at the code you added.

Comment: You didn't understand. Think in terms of SQL. Let's say you are looking for COUNT(PersonID). Against which column are you looking to obtain the count? Is there any relationship between *that* column and `PersonID`? Are they in the same dimension or different?

Comment: I guess it's Transaction. You would end up with multiple instances of a person ID in the result if that person had more than one transaction

Comment: Then the parent-member suggestion is misleading. I will have to edit my answer.

Comment: Error message please?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the query works but the cells show #Error in that column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93821/discussion-between-sourava-and-clockework).

Answer (score 0):

Untested as currently I'm away from AdvWrks but I will prototype in that cube later:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Count] AS
COUNT(
  NONEMPTY(
    EXISTS(
      [Person].[Person ID].[Person ID].MEMBERS
     ,{[Person].[Person ID].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT}
    )
  , [Measures].[Value]
)
...
```